# Implement search similar to native contacts search?

Tags: ios, search, nspredicate

On native contacts app, when you try to search for contacts, you type some string and if contact first name / last name / company etc.. begin with this string, contact will be shown.

To make matters more complex, you can type something like Mi Ric and search will find Michael Richardson. Also Ric Mi will get me Michael Richardson.

I have made copy of contact record into my local core data store, and now my first instinct is to use `NSFetchedResultsController` and some nice predicate.

But how would i go about this predicate? If person record has up to 3 words, should i query each word with beginsWith? Can this even be done i one predicate?

Comment: You can use a Regex in a predicate. I posted a possible answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156932/how-to-make-search-bar-as-iphone-contact-app-or-search-bar-which-handles-more-th/42162841#42162841

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i use for word base predicate:

```
+ (NSPredicate *)wordBasedPredicateForString:(NSString *)searchString withProperty:(NSString *)property
{

   // searchString = [searchString stringForSearch];
    NSArray *searchStrings = [searchString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSMutableArray<NSPredicate *> *subPredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *string in searchStrings)
        if (![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSString *mainString = [property stringByAppendingString:@" CONTAINS[cd] "];        
            mainString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ CONTAINS[cd] %%@",property];
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:mainString, string];
            [subPredicates addObject:predicate];
        }


    if ([searchString containsString:@" "] && subPredicates.count > 0) {
        NSString *mainString = [property stringByAppendingString:@" CONTAINS[cd] "];
        mainString = [mainString stringByAppendingString:@"' '"];

        NSPredicate *emptySpacePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:mainString, nil];

        [subPredicates addObject:emptySpacePredicate];
    }


    NSCompoundPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];

    return predicate;
}
```

let assume that we have a `Contact` object with a `name` property

```
NSPredicate *namePredicate = [self wordBasedPredicateForString:searchString withProperty: @"name"];
```

then filter the array:

```
NSArray *results = [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:namePredicate];
```

and of course you can make multiple word base predicates for name, company, address etc and make one compoundPredicate like this:

```
orPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[namePredicate, addressPredicate, phonePredicate]];
```

Hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this solution

Let's take look of `MyContact` class

```
class MyContact: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var contact_id: String // Primary key
    @NSManaged var firstname: String
    @NSManaged var lastname: String

    var fullName: String {
        return firstname + " " + lastname
    }

}
```

Now you have `fullName` string in your object. so you can easily fire predicate on it. it doesn't matter, your `searchString` is match your first name or last name.

Now Add search logic:-

```
var currentContacts : [MyContact] = []
var contacts : [MyContact] = []
```

Your tableView delegate method used `currentContacts` array and `contacts` array just hold all contact.

You can filter your `contacts` array as per your search string.

```
currentContacts = contacts.filter { (element: MyContact) -> Bool in
    return element.fullName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString)
}
tableView.reloadData()
```

Hope it will help ;)